# create a column in a pandas dataframe which calculates the difference between two rows

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column called `df[column_name]`, where the result is the difference between the current row and the row above it.

In the case of the first row there is nothing above it so change is 0. for the second row change is 2 (26-24) and so on.

```
dates | data | result
24-09    24      0
25-09    26      2
26-09    27      1
27-09    28      1
28-09    26     -2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `diff` method for this, together with `fillna` to fill the first NaN with a 0:

```
df['data'].diff().fillna(0)
```

Example:

```
In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame({'data':[24,26,27,28,26]})

In [7]: df['result'] = df['data'].diff().fillna(0)

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
   data  result
0    24       0
1    26       2
2    27       1
3    28       1
4    26      -2
```

Comment: in the meantime do you know if it's possible to then count in another dataframe the positive run of +4 from 25-09 and 27-09 and store it in a separate dataframe which has three columns, start date, end date, and run (which would be positive or negative)?

Comment: Best to just ask a new question (as it seems something really different, and comments are not really handy for that)